# Please recommend textbook with exercises and full solutions, for a first course on Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

My Intro to Real Analysis course covers topics such as:

Real numbers and sequences. Metric spaces, compactness and connectedness.
Sequences and series of functions, power series; modes of convergence.
Interchange of limiting processes; differentiation of integrals. Function spaces; Weierstrass approximation theorem.

My course's textbook is *Real Analysis and Applications: Theory in Practice* by Davidson and Donsig. The problem with this book is that it doesn't have any solutions for its exercises. Anyone here know of a similar book that covers the same  topics and has similar  exercises, **but with solutions?**

Comment: I think you're supposed to supply the solutions!

Comment: It is highly unusual for a mathematics textbook to have solutions for its exercises. That's not to say that you can't occasionally find solutions flying around the web ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real analysis text books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790213/real-analysis-text-books)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [*The How and Why of One Variable Calculus* by Amol Sasane](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2090308) because it  furnishes many color diagrams, **and detailed solutions for every exercise in full view!**

I STRONGLY DISAGREE with [JYM](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/537957/jym)'s  [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2725712). DON'T use Royden's Real Analysis as an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You can found solutions on the web for" Royden, Real analysis" . But it is not an introductory text.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Abbott's *[Understanding Analysis](http://ndl.ethernet.edu.et/bitstream/123456789/88631/1/2015_Book_UnderstandingAnalysis.pdf)* is a great introduction with elegant proofs and intuitive explanations.