# Solution Manual for Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, Chapter 12 (Multivariable Differential Calculus)

Tags: reference-request

Does there exist a **solution manual** of **Apostol's Mathematical Analysis** which contains the solution of the exercises given in **Chapter 12 (Multivariable Differential Calculus)**? I found one in library genesis but that contains only chapter 1-9. It'd be much appreciated if anyone can give me any lead. Thanks in advance.

Comment: alternatively, you can see if your solutions are correct here, in mathexchange

Comment: @Masacroso you mean by posting my solutions as verification posts? I only have them in my copies and not typed out..

Comment: yes, I mean that. I usually do this when Im not sure if the solution of some exercise is correct or not

Comment: It's not always reliable, but you can try using SLADER. [link](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780201002881-mathematical-analysis-2nd-edition/)