# Solution verification post : Problem $12.1$, Mathematical Analysis, Apostol

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

As a continuation of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910662/solution-manual-for-apostols-mathematical-analysis-chapter-12-multivariable-d), I'm starting to post my solutions (or attempts) to the exercise problems of Chapter 12 (Multivariable Differential Calculus), [Mathematical Analysis by Apostol](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201002884) (suggested by [Masacroso](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173262/masacroso)). Since I'm essentially self-studying, I'd really appreciate if anyone checks the solutions and let me know if there is any gap in my arguments or if there exists any cleverer solutions. Thank you.

---

**Problem $12.1.$** Let $S$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function with finite partial derivative $D_1f,\dots,D_nf$ on $S$. If $f$ has a local maximum or a local minimum at a point $c$ in $S$, prove that $D_kf\left(c\right)=0 \,\,\forall \,k$.

---

**Solution.** Suppose that $f$ has a local maximum at $c \in S$. This implies that $\exists \delta>0$ such that
$$f(c) \geq f(x) \text{ for all } x \in B_{\delta}(c)=\left\{y \in S : \left\Vert y-c \right\Vert < \delta \right\} \tag1$$
Let $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Now,
$$D_kf(c)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+he_k)-f(c)}{h} \tag2$$
It is given that $(2)$ exists finitely, then
$$D_kf(c)=\lim_{h \to 0;\,h \in (0,\delta)} \frac{f(c+he_k)-f(c)}{h} \leq 0 \tag3$$
On the other hand,
$$D_kf(c)=\lim_{h \to 0;\,h \in (-\delta,0)} \frac{f(c+he_k)-f(c)}{h} \geq 0 \tag4$$
$(3)$ and $(4)$ $\Rightarrow$ $D_kf(c)=0$. This holds for every $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and hence we are done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your solution is correct. The same argument is used in the one-dimensional case. In fact, you could reduce your problem to the one-dimensional case by considering
$$g_k(t):= f(a+t e_k)$$
in a neighboorhoud of $0$ (exists because $S$ is open) and fixed $a \in S$. Here $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ denote the 'standard basis' of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assuming that $f$ has a local maximum in $a \in S$ implies that $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ have a local maximum in $t=0$. Thus we have
$$0=g'_k(0) = \left. \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x_k} f(x) \right|_{x=a}.$$